# Horizontal, Slanted, Stacked Lines in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a relative beginner to LaTeX and am currently learning TikZ. For practice, I decided to recreate the tube marking guide provided for Estes model rockets in the instructions (pictured below).

[image]

I have reasonably accurately reproduced almost all of it (perhaps not very efficiently, but reproduced, nonetheless). Here is my current code and its output (note that the externally-referenced Estes logo can be found on [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=estes%20logo&safe=strict&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS828US828&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTu56n1KPjAhVjiOAKHeUCBs4Q_AUIECgB&biw=1440&bih=739#imgrc=r7bwBvOZDzeiHM:)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}




\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5.0625in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (0.625in,0) -- (0.625in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (1.875in,0) -- (1.875in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (3.1875in,0) -- (3.1875in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (4.45in,0) -- (4.45in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,0.5in) -- (0.25in,0.5in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,1.375in) -- (0.25in,1.375in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (4.8125in,0.5in) -- (5.0625in,0.5in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (4.8125in,1.375in) -- (5.0625in,1.375in);
        \filldraw[color=black, fill=gray!30, thick] (5.0625in,0) rectangle (5.375in,1.875in);
        \filldraw[color=black, fill=white, very thick] (1in,0.25in) -- (1in,1.625in) -- (4.5in,1.4375in) -- (4.5in,0.4375in) -- cycle;
        \draw[black, very thick, loosely dashed] (2.5in,0.33in) -- (2.5in,1.545in);
        \draw[black, very thick, loosely dashed] (3.6875in,0.394in) -- (3.6875in,1.481in);
        \node[rotate=90] (Estes) at (1.23in,0.9375in) {\includegraphics[width=0.17\textwidth]{Images/estes-logo.png}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (0.1in,0.9375in) {\footnotesize \textbf{LL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (0.725in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (1.975in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (3.2875in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (4.55in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (2.1in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{3}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (3in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{2}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (4in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Big Bertha tube marking guide.}
    \label{fig:bigbertha}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

[image]

By my estimation, the only thing that I am missing at this point is the stacked, slanted lines in the gray box at the picture's right. **How can these lines be created?**

I have tried `grid` with `yslant`, but this did not cut off exactly at the top and bottom and there were remnant vertical lines.

Open to all suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I focus on the lines here. They can be achieved with a `path picture`. For larger pictures you may need to increase  `35`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}




\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5.0625in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (0.625in,0) -- (0.625in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (1.875in,0) -- (1.875in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (3.1875in,0) -- (3.1875in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (4.45in,0) -- (4.45in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,0.5in) -- (0.25in,0.5in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,1.375in) -- (0.25in,1.375in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (4.8125in,0.5in) -- (5.0625in,0.5in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (4.8125in,1.375in) -- (5.0625in,1.375in);
        \filldraw[color=black, fill=gray!30, thick,path picture={
        \draw foreach \X in {-2,-1,...,35}
         {([yshift=\X*4pt]path picture bounding box.south east)
          -- ([yshift=\X*4pt+3pt]path picture bounding box.south west)};
        }] 
        (5.0625in,0) rectangle (5.375in,1.875in);
        \filldraw[color=black, fill=white, very thick] (1in,0.25in) -- (1in,1.625in) -- (4.5in,1.4375in) -- (4.5in,0.4375in) -- cycle;
        \draw[black, very thick, loosely dashed] (2.5in,0.33in) -- (2.5in,1.545in);
        \draw[black, very thick, loosely dashed] (3.6875in,0.394in) -- (3.6875in,1.481in);
        %\node[rotate=90] (Estes) at (1.23in,0.9375in) {\includegraphics[width=0.17\textwidth]{Images/estes-logo.png}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (0.1in,0.9375in) {\footnotesize \textbf{LL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (0.725in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (1.975in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (3.2875in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (4.55in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (2.1in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{3}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (3in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{2}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (4in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Big Bertha tube marking guide.}
    \label{fig:bigbertha}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve the following result using the `patterns` `tikzlibrary` and the `pattern=north west lines` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}




\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5.0625in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (0.625in,0) -- (0.625in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (1.875in,0) -- (1.875in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (3.1875in,0) -- (3.1875in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick, <->] (4.45in,0) -- (4.45in,1.875in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,0.5in) -- (0.25in,0.5in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (0,1.375in) -- (0.25in,1.375in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (4.8125in,0.5in) -- (5.0625in,0.5in);
        \draw[black, very thick] (4.8125in,1.375in) -- (5.0625in,1.375in);
        \filldraw[color=black, thick, pattern=north west lines] (5.0625in,0) rectangle (5.375in,1.875in);
        \filldraw[color=black, fill=white, very thick] (1in,0.25in) -- (1in,1.625in) -- (4.5in,1.4375in) -- (4.5in,0.4375in) -- cycle;
        \draw[black, very thick, loosely dashed] (2.5in,0.33in) -- (2.5in,1.545in);
        \draw[black, very thick, loosely dashed] (3.6875in,0.394in) -- (3.6875in,1.481in);
        \node[rotate=90] (Estes) at (1.23in,0.9375in) {\includegraphics[width=0.17\textwidth]{Images/estes-logo.png}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (0.1in,0.9375in) {\footnotesize \textbf{LL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (0.725in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (1.975in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (3.2875in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (4.55in,0.2in) {\footnotesize \textbf{FL}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (2.1in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{3}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (3in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{2}};
        \node[rotate=90] at (4in,0.9375in) {\huge \textbf{1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Big Bertha tube marking guide.}
    \label{fig:bigbertha}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

If you want to keep the gray background and want to draw the pattern on top of it, use `\filldraw[color=black, preaction={fill, gray!30},, thick, pattern=north west lines]`

[image]